# Tool for writing javascript code

Tags: javascript

I tried different tool for writing javascript code such as netBeam and eclipse.

They are great tool for developing javascript library but they have the disadvantages to rely on java which is not very fast at all for my laptop (1GB of memory and 1.1Ghz CPU).

Can you please suggest me an open source tool to help developers writing JavaScript libraries?

Comment: Ever heard of Google ? And seriously, who develops on a 1GB machine ? That's totally stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tons of options.

- [Vim](http://vim.org/)
- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/)
- [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (and friends)
- [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [SCiTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)
- [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)
- [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (or [e Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/), its Windows clone)
- [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)
- And more

A javascript library is just a regular piece of code. Try several, and pick whichever one you like best.

For the debugging part, the two major browsers (talking about actual browsers, not IE) Chrome and FireFox both have great debugging tools. Chrome has the built in [Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) (Ctrl-Shift-I to launch) and ff has [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Use something light like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) coupled with Google Chrome and/or Firebug which provide a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) and debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I hear good things about [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/). You can run it standalone or plug it into eclipse.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe Aptana is written in Java.

Comment: If you're a developer writing javascript librarys, why not get the tools that make your job doable...like a new laptop?

Answer (score 0):

i Used Google Web Toolkit for Writing JavaScript Code it's easy and fastest.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Noticed now that you were looking for an Open Source one, while you have to buy the one I suggested. My choice for an open source solution is [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/).

---

Are you looking for an editor?

So far the best I could find is [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

It's lightweight, fast and with many features. It aims at increasing your productivity by using only needed things.

So far there is a good support for JavaScript, with many snippets, auto completion and good syntax highlighting. You can write a function statement by only typing fun+TAB for example. So far it's the best editor I've tried.