# Which IDE should I use for Intern automation tool?

Tags: intern

I am currently working on a automation project using Intern automation tool, but I am currently finding it difficult to find an IDE to write code, compile and run. Even I am finding it difficult to debug my tests.

Comment: Is this question referring to the Intern JavaScript testing tool?

Answer (score 0):

Any tools for writing JavaScript would be suitable ([Tool for writing javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371107/tool-for-writing-javascript-code))

For debugging, you can use node-inspector ([Here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/05/23/how-can-i-debug-intern-tests/) is an article about debugging Intern)

I use [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), quite happy. It has a very convenient debugger.